# Way to implement looking for NoneType within a for loop?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

Having issues with trying to pull NoneTypes out of this for loop, just so I don't crash my bot with this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command rank:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Life\discordbot\main.py", line 232, in rank
    await ranking_menu.start(ctx)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\menus\__init__.py", line 967, in start
    await super().start(ctx, channel=channel, wait=wait)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\menus\__init__.py", line 707, in start
    self.message = msg = await self.send_initial_message(ctx, channel)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\menus\__init__.py", line 962, in send_initial_message
    kwargs = await self._get_kwargs_from_page(page)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\menus\__init__.py", line 939, in _get_kwargs_from_page
    value = await discord.utils.maybe_coroutine(self._source.format_page, self, page)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 343, in maybe_coroutine
    return await value
  File "D:\Life\discordbot\main.py", line 207, in format_page
    table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n'
  File "D:\Life\discordbot\main.py", line 207, in <genexpr>
    table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "E:\Programing\discordbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

It would have to be put in this line tho, otherwize the code doesn't work as intended, and i'm having a pain in the butt trying to do that. Any and all help is appreciated!

```
        table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n'
                for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))
```

Thanks again guys.

iF needed, here is the class it's apart of! and entries is from a returned amount of rows in a database

```
class LocalXpMenu(ListPageSource):
    def __init__(self, ctx, data):
        self.ctx = ctx
        super().__init__(data, per_page = 10)

    async def write_page(self, menu, fields=[]):
         offset = (menu.current_page * self.per_page) + 1
         len_data = len(self.entries)

         embed = Embed(title="Server XP Leaderboard",
                       colour=self.ctx.author.colour)
         embed.set_thumbnail(url = self.ctx.guild.icon_url)
         embed.set_footer(text = f"{offset:,} - {min(len_data, offset+self.per_page-1):,} of {len_data:,} members.")

         for name, value in fields:
             embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)
         return embed

    async def format_page(self, menu, entries):
        fields = []

        table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n'
                for idx, entry in enumerate(entries)))

        fields.append(("Ranks", table))

        return await self.write_page(menu, fields)
```

Comment: What is the program supposed to do if ```get_user(entry)``` is None? Skip?

Comment: yes, sorry for taking so long to get back to you, I had a busy day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter first to choose only non-None entries.

```py
mapped_entries = map(lambda entry: entry + [self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0])], entries)

filtered_entries = filter(lambda entry: entry[3] != None, mapped_entries)

table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {entry[3].name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n' for idx, entry in enumerate(filtered_entries)))
```

Note that `idx` in this example will exclude entries with `None` `get_user` result. If you want to enclude those, you would have to include indices in `mapped_entries` and use those instead.

Answer (score 2):

Add condition with `for` loop like -

```py
table = ("\n".join(f'{idx + 1}. {self.ctx.bot.get_user(entry[0]).name} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]} \n' for idx, entry in enumerate(entries) if (entry and (len(entry) >= 3))))
```

Comment: I tried this but I still seem to be getting the same error, so I'm not really sure what's up